# Java access bridge - unable to spy java application in Blue prism

Tags: java, blueprism, java-access-bridge

When I am trying to launch a java application from the application modeller getting an error as:
**"Error - Failed to launch application - Could not initialise Java Access Bridge support - Failed to load Java Access Bridge DLL. The file could not be found in any of the following expected locations - 
Application Directory: C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll System Directory: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll"**.

And then I downloaded java access bridge 2.0.2 and copied the dll **"WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll "** to **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64"** path and enabled JAB from cmd and then it worked. **But still not able to spy java elements**.
jre version is 1.6. Any ideas anyone? Or am i missing anything?

Sreejith

Comment: I've personally had a bad experience with the Java Spy mode. I would recommend either resorting to UI Spy mode (BP v6+) or Region mode as BP takes ages to spy elements in Java Spy mode (after a long struggle to make it work).

Comment: Hi @Jerry! Client is not ready for an update to to BP v6. And region mode also not working there. Its an oracle application. Looks like no hope.

Comment: Not working? Weird, I've never experienced that. My client was using an oracle system too (still is). Performance was more than 10 times better with region when compared to java mode.

Comment: Finally! got the solution. Still not sure why its happening. Since BP was opened in administrator mode it was not recognizing the java elements(No idea why). When opened in normal way it started working. Anyways Thanks @Jerry

Comment: All right, that's awesome. Good luck! Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: I guess JAB enabled for user, but not admin account.